# WooCommerce - rename /product/ and /product-category/ slugs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I'm trying to figure out how to rename or translate the `/product/` and `/product-category/` slugs in WooCommerce.

I don't want to remove them completely, I just want to rename them to `/lesson/` and `/lesson-category/`

Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on the WordPress permalinks settings page. See `product permalinks`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Replace **product/** with your slug name example *lesson/* and the same for the product categories to *lesson-category*